# hiding urls in a popup window

Tags: javascript

I am having problem in hiding url in a popup window in Mozilla.I tried using location=no in the popup window parameter but it was no help.Any suggestion or alternative.Is there any way to encrypt the url using javascript and decrypt using java?

Comment: @Jigar JoshiThank you very much for the reply.Will that hide the url in the addressbar or hide the addressbar itself of the popup window?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're opening new window in javascript then you can write:-

```
var win = window.open("about:blank","");
```

And the from the variable win you can acess the html of the new opened window. Now add an iframe win the body of the new window and set the src to your required src. Like:-

```
win.document.write('<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;border: none;"></iframe>');
```